# Find 5 most purchased products exercise sorted by month

Tags: r

i'm trying to learn how to use R but i have this exercise still too difficult for me so i'd like to have suggestions about a possible implementation.

Create a job to generate, for each 2015 month, 5 most sold products
followed by amount of sold pieces.

#### My data input is:

2015-9-8,salad

2015-8-30,cookies,cheese,salad,bread

2015-11-21,bread

2015-12-2,vine

2015-3-12,cookies,bread,milk

...

I need help to create an output file containing result like.

#### Example:

2015-01: bread 852, milk 753, meat 544, vine 501, fish 488

2015-02: milk 744, butter 655, eggs 585, beer 498, bread 457

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination `tidyverse` packages (`dplyr` & `tidyr`) and `lubridate` like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data <- read.table(text = "2015-9-8,salad

          2015-8-30,cookies,cheese,salad,bread

          2015-11-21,bread

          2015-12-2,vine

          2015-3-12,cookies,bread,milk", 
          header = F)
data %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("date", letters[1:5]), sep = ",") %>% 
  gather(key, item, -date, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date), 
         month = floor_date(date, unit = "month")) %>% 
  group_by(month, item) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  spread(item, n, fill = 0)


## A tibble: 5 x 7
## Groups:   month [5]
#    month      bread cheese cookies  milk salad  vine
#    <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 2015-03-01     1      0       1     1     0     0
#  2 2015-08-01     1      1       1     0     1     0
#  3 2015-09-01     0      0       0     0     1     0
#  4 2015-11-01     1      0       0     0     0     0
#  5 2015-12-01     0      0       0     0     0     1
```